# SQL Server database with different language from the instance default

Tags: sql-server, datetime

My main production database is a SQL Server 2014 with default language set to English and, of course, dates treated as `MM/dd/yyyy`.

Now, for compatibility reasons with a legacy application, I must create a new database with language = Italian and dates treated as `dd/MM/yyyy`.

Googling a bit, I discovered that I must declare this new database with the **partial containment** option, which allows me to further select Italian as the database language.

So far so good, but when I try to create the new database the following error appears:

> The sp_configure value 'contained database authentication' must be set to 1 in order to create a contained database.
>   You may need to use RECONFIGURE to set the value_in_use.

And the suggested procedure to be executed is:

```
sp_configure 'contained database authentication', 1;  
GO  

RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

The question is: this is my production database and I'm tampering with a global instance parameter, is this safe for the existing databases or could I experience possible impacts?

Comment: Language is (normally) set at login level, not database. Why not simply change the language for the login for that application?

Comment: Do you mean in the connection string ?

Comment: No, when you create the login. `CREATE LOGIN bob WITH DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[British]...;` (obviously use the language you need).

Comment: @Larnu thanks, it worked great !! If you post your suggestion as an answer I can mark it as appropriate. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't set the language setting (normally) at database level. Language settings can, however, easily be set for a specific login; then regardless of what database the Login is connected to it will use that Language's settings.

When creating a login, you set the language as part of the `WITH` clause. For example:

```
CREATE LOGIN bob WITH DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[British]...;
```

This would mean that the Login `[bob]` would (by default) use the British language (which for dates means that they would be interpreted in the format `dd/MM/yyyy`).

As you're wanting the application to use a specific language for the database it connects to, if you simply change the login to use the relevant default language, any connections it makes will use that language (unless it overrides it within the statement).